# Binary Relation definition in Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

Do binary relations have multiple definitions?  For example equality:

$$= \subset U \times U$$
$$(a,b) \in =$$

appears used typically as:
$$a = b, =(a,b)$$

which would require a functional definition to truth values:
$$= : U \times U \rightarrow 2$$

$$((a,b),t) \in =$$

Comment: Not very clear... The $\in$ binary predicate is part of the language of set theory; thus, we have it from the start.

Comment: The "subset" binary relation $\subseteq$ is a defined symbol that we add to the basic language with a definition: $A \subseteq B \text { iff } \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$

Comment: In a formal context we cannot define them following tour proposal because we have no "universal set" $U$.

Comment: Maybe useful [Inner model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My point is the equality relation, from what I have seen, is defined as a set of binary pairs as the relation.   At the same time, the equality function, as used typically in mathematics, is these pairs paired with truth values.  So why isn't the equality function defined as the later?